# Can not get window height and width in phonegap (android)

Tags: cordova

I used $(window).width() and $(window).height() to get the screen size of webview in android device. But sometime the return value is 0. I don't know why. Please help me to resolve this problem. Sorry about my English :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me this function works perfectly on Android and iOS

```
function SetElementHeight(){
screenHeight=$('.ui-mobile').outerHeight(true);
screenWidth=$('.ui-mobile').outerWidth(true);
//console.log("outerHeight= "+ screenHeight);
//console.log("outerWidth= "+ screenWidth);

}
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event,ui){
 SetElementHeight();
});`
```